NextJS website running on Amazon Lightsail went down after a few days. How can I keep it from happening again?
I made a personal website for a career fair last week and spent a lot of time trying to get it to be visible, and I managed to get it to stay up long enough to show it off to everyone at the career fair, but six days later, I was writing a link to it somewhere and when I tried to test the link, I got a 503 error, meaning that sometime within that six-day gap (I'm not sure when), the NextJS application server went down, but not the web server, and I have no idea why this happened.
Here's the situation (Keep in mind, this is my first time trying to run a website, so I'm probably doing a million things wrong):
I have a website that I made with NextJS because I wanted to use React and that was what React's documentation recommended.
I am hosting the site on an Amazon Lightsail instance with the Node.js template (or whatever it was called). I realize that AWS Amplify is designed specifically for NextJS, but Lightsail was cheaper, and I thought it would suit my purposes better since - for now at least - the site is just four pages that would be static if it wasn't for React.
The Lightsail instance uses Apache as the web server, and I already got that to serve the content from the NPM/NextJS application server, so that isn't the problem (I assume).
The process(es) started by npm run start to run the application server are not startup programs (I thought this would make debugging easier since I can control when the server starts), and they are run using the default user (the "bitnami" user that the Lightsail instance came with), in case any of this stuff matters.
To get the server to stay up long enough to do the career fair, I ran these commands (nohup didn't work for me for some reason, but I don't remember why):
cd <folder where the website project is>
npm run start
^z
bg
disown -h

After I found out that the website went down, I wrote this script to detect if it was down, then restart it if it was, and I had it run as a cron job every night at midnight. (This was a temporary solution until I could find and fix the actual problem.)
#! /bin/bash

if ps -e | grep "npm"
then
    exit
else
    cd <folder where the website project is>
    npm start & disown
fi

exit

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong and what I should be doing, or at least what the problem might be. I will try to answer any questions you have and give you any information you still need if I can figure it out. Thank you all in advance.

There are many reasons your instance crashed. There should be logs somewhere to allow you to track what happened and correct it.
What you need to keep your process up and running is a process manager. I'd recommend PM2, as it will monitor your app, record logs, and restart it when it fails.
The following article can guide you further:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352826/can-i-use-pm2-to-keep-a-next-js-app-running
There's an open source version and a paid version. The open source should be more than enough for a 4 page site.

I will have to try that out.

I just tried it, and the server is running, but I don't know if I will notice if it goes down again considering how long it took me to notice the last time. (In other words, I don't know how to tell when I can safely mark this answer as the solution.) In any case, thank you for your help.

you can check the status in the pm2 console. it will even tell you how many times it has restarted your app and provide you easy access to the logs to diagnose any problem

That’s cool. Thank you for letting me know. I was also planning on checking on it one week after I ran it, and one month after I ran it.

The server hasn't gone down again. I am going to accept this as the answer. Thank you for all your help @Luis Alberto Barandiaran.
